# Wondering if my Nikon lens is broken

Tags: nikon, dslr, troubleshooting

I have a Nikon D50 (not sure what lens right now but could check if necessary).  I recently took it traveling with me, and I'm not sure if I damaged the lens or if a setting is off. It's making all of my photos really dark and/or blue tinted. I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this or knows what it means. The setting is already on auto.

Here are two example pictures (taken indoors) which show the issues I'm having:

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Photos taken at night seem to be OK.

[image: night]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you believe this to be a lens fault rather than a camera fault? If you can, find someone with another lens and another camera and test all combinations. Also, try a factory reset on your camera which should rule out any funny settings.

Comment: For what it's worth: the standard lens with the early D50 was the *AF-S Nikkor 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6G ED*. A DX lens. I think the later D40 had a VR version but I'm not sure if any D50 kits included this.

Answer (score 3):

As @philipkendall says, it may be a camera body issue. If some images are ok, while others are not, it suggests the lens (which is unchanged across pictures) is ok.

It may be that either one or both of the white balance and exposure compensation settings might have been knocked.

## White Balance

If this is set incorrectly this may explain why some of the photos look blue. On the back of the D50, hold the **WB** button and rotate the command dial and ensure the setting is on **Auto**. If this is set to daylight or flash by mistake, for example, this would account for the blue tones.

## Exposure Compensation

Next, the images might be too dark if the exposure compensation is too low. To check this, there's an exposure compensation button on the top of the D50 next to the shutter release. It looks like a plus/minus sign, like this: http://djshawphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/5_1.jpg

Hold this, and rotate the command dial to make sure this is set to **0**.

## If these don't work

If you can, check the lens on another Nikon body. It will work on any digital Nikon. This will confirm if it's the lens or body that's at fault.

If it's the body, given the age of the D50 you may want to consider simply buying a new, or more recent second-hand, body.